# Serilog and Test Unit

Tags: .net, serilog

We wrote a library for .net core 2.1 and it works with a asp core 2.1 appliance.

We use serilog extensively instead console but when we use test unit we are not able to log anything.

It works very well in production, when we run the code in asp.core app.

We log using:

```
public class MyClass
{
        private readonly Serilog.ILogger _logger = Serilog.Log.Logger;

        public async Task MyFunction(string url)
        {
           _logger.Debug(">>>> cheched <<<<<");
        }
}
```

We configure the test unit like that:

```
   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
             .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
             .WriteTo.File(path: "log.txt", restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Verbose)
             .WriteTo.Debug(LogEventLevel.Verbose)
              .CreateLogger();
```

Where's the issue?

Comment: "_when we use test unit we are not able to log anything_" - Does that mean that no logs are being to the file or to the console? Can you show how / where you are setting up Serilog in your tests, and an example of test that uses it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a testing framework for .NET called `test unit`? Is that the correct name, or are you using a different framework such as `xUnit`, `NUnit`, `MSTest`, etc.?

Comment: We are using MSTest